# How to show my App in setting Screen in iOS

Tags: ios

I have a small doubt on iOS. I created an app and run this app on simulator and device also. And i want to see that app in setting screen like below screenshots.

[image]

Like facebbok, Flickr, Twitter, i want see my app here. What i have to do ?

I have to do in coding ya how please help me.

Comment: i think it will helpful for you https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

Answer (score 1):

- Create New->Resource->Settings Bundle
- Choose your preferences that you want from `Root.plist`

See this [link](http://codehappily.wordpress.com/2014/03/18/ios-how-to-create-an-ios-settings-entry-for-your-app-using-settings-bundle/) for more step by step instructions.

Here is the link to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) site

Answer (score 1):

If your app use some service,like location service and notification,your app is auto set into settings.

If not,create setting bundle,like Neo said.